# Внедрение микроразметки wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Имеется сайт на wp, нужно привести меню к виду:

```html
    <nav itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
 <ul class="menu">
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="https://123.ru/">Главная</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="https://123.ru/author-bloga/">Автор</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Сейчас оно вот такого вида:

```html
<div
id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse"><ul
class="nav navbar-nav"><li
id="menu-item-1992" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-1992"><a
title="Главная" href="https://123.ru/">Главная</a></li><li
id="menu-item-1993" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1993"><a
title="О нас" href="https://123.ru/">О нас</a><ul
class="sub-menu"><li
id="menu-item-2142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2142"><a
title="Документы" href="https://123.ru/">Документы</a></li>
```

Не соображу где правится, весь шаблон ископал, так и не нашел.

Comment: Меню генерируется в `wp_nav_menu()`, где используется несколько хуков для модификации как классов, так и всего html меню. Но вам надо не надо. Во-первых, поломаете функционал показа меню и подменю. Весь css на этих классах висит, и иногда и js. А во-вторых, вы всерьез полагаете, что лучше разбираетесь в SEO, чем команда создателей WP?

Comment: Микроразметка нужна, это я уже сам себе не единожды доказал и увидел на примере, только ранее работал с другими cms и там все это проще внедрялось, а тут под руку попался проект над которым работали ранее, все запутали, что и концов не сыщешь, а надо всего лишь добавить атрибуты в ссылки, само меню я нашел где обособить, а вот каждый отельный пункт не разобрался.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu    https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_items   https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_nav_menu_objects

Comment: Добавьте свои классы, имеющиеся не удаляйте, сломаете сайт

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться. :)